# How to split into table rows

Tags: php

I've tried many solutions given here but I can't manage to split this piece of code into multiple table rows. Many thanks in advance!!

Update: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I want to have 5 cols and start a new table row after that hope this helps. Thanks for all the answers!

Update2: Somebody who can help me out here? The code from Minesh is close but I still get errors, see comments below. Many, many thanks in advance!!

```
$opties.='<b>'.$option['name'].':</b><br /><table><tr>';

      foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { 

        $opties.= '<td><img src="image/cache/'.$option_thumb.'" /><br />'.$option_value['name'].'</td>';

      }
       $opties.='</tr></table>';
```

Comment: Get more details, paste the result of `print_r($option)`

Comment: $option_thumb is not defined

Comment: what is the question? why did you tagged mysql? see http://stackoverflow.com/faq before posting your question

Comment: You say you want to split the result into table rows (`<tr></tr>`), yet you are creating table columns (`<td></td>`)... I'm confuzed.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I want to have 5 cols and start a new <tr> after that

Comment: Somebody who can help me out here? The code from Minesh is close but I still get errors, see comments below. Many, many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because in loop you are only putting TD and not TR.
You need to maintain **counter** which is incremented in each loop by 1.

Then inside **foreach** loop, you can check using modulo operator if 4 columns are printed you need to complete TR tag and start new TR tag.

@UPDATED: Based on user's comment of 5 cols

See below code :

```
$opties.='<b>'.$option['name'].':</b><br /><table><tr>';
$cnt=0;
foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { 
    if($cnt % 5 == 0 && $cnt > 1) 
        $opties .= '</tr><tr>';
    $opties .= '<td><img src="image/cache/'.$option_thumb.'" /><br />'.$option_value['name'].'</td>';
    $cnt++;
}
if(count($option['option_value']) % 5 > 0)
    $opties.='</tr>';
$opties.='</table>';
```

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I want to have 5 cols and start a new table row after that hope this helps. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry it took me so long to reply. There is something wrong with the <tr> or </tr> tags because I'm getting errors related to this. It's kind of difficult to debug because the results of this are send to tcpdf for generating a pdf file.

Comment: I think I've found the problem, if I've have 6 results, I'm missing 2 <td></td> tags. Am I right about this? And how to fix this?

Comment: Any change you can help me out here @Minesh?

Comment: @user2017772 I have updated code as per your comments of 5 columns, also made minor change in checking for 5 columns condition.. see now

Comment: Thanks for the update, still no luck :( 
Forgive me in case I'm asking a stupid question but what if I've 7 database results? Looks to me we are missing 3 <td></td> tags in that case?

Comment: solution found, this line shouldn't be there: `if(count($option['option_value']) % 5 > 0)`
Thanks for your time @Minesh!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for but try:

```
$opties.='<b>'.$option['name'].':</b><br /><table>';

      foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { 

        $opties.= '<tr><td><img src="image/cache/'.$option_thumb.'" /><br />'.$option_value['name'].'</td></tr>';

      }
$opties.='</table>';
```

Couse if you want to create multiple rows you must use `<tr>` tag inside your `foreach` loop.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I want to have 5 cols and start a new table row after that hope this helps. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

First of all

you should have 2 loops

```
foreach($opties as $rows => $column)
    //now it's row so echo 
    <tr>
    foreach( $column as $key => $value) {
        // now it's <td> turn
        <td> data </td>
    }
    </tr>
}
```

This is just pseudo code to explain the 2 loops

Hope this help ;)

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I want to have 5 cols and start a new table row after that hope this helps. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what your array contains, so I'm giving you a more generic example.

```
$array  = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 5);
$output = '<table>' . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($chunks as $row) {
    $output .= '<tr>';

    foreach ($row as $col) {
        $output .= '<td>' . $col . '</td>';
    }

    $output .= '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
};

$output .= '</table>';

echo $output;
```

This is just a slightly different take on @Piya's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean with I can't tell what your array contains? The code I posted in my question is all there is... I'm not sure how to paste my code into this, it would be great if you can give me a hint, I don't have very much coding experience. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I can tell that `$option['option_value']` is an array, but I don't know what elenemts it has. The best advice I can give you is to study the code you've been given until you understand how it works, then apply it to your problem

Comment: The array contains mysql results so each table generated will contain other elements.